# How to specify in QTP's Object Repository, that I want to find Web Button object by title

Tags: automated-tests, qtp

I have rich web application with a lot of dynamic stuff (used ExtJS 3.0). I want to find Web Button using HP QuickTest Pro 10. This web button have only one property , that can uniquely identify it: title. But if I define that object in Object Repository with Description Property Title= it doesn't find it.

Please, advise me what can I do in that situation? I've tried to use object.title=Some value as well, but it doesn't helped.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a new property "attribute/title" to the button class, and make that an identification property in the object identification configuration.

The "attribute/" prefix allows you to use any attribute that you can access via the Object property.

Comment: You're right about `attribute/` but your explanation is a bit misleading. The set of properties for identification and for `GetROProperty` are identical, `attribute/` allows accessing properties that are available via the `.Object` property, in the Object spy you can see the separate properties depending if you select the **Native** or **Identification** radio button.

Comment: I would recommend editing your question so as not to mislead anyone (some people may not read comments). P.S. When answering people's comments please use the @user notation so it shows up in the alerts.

Comment: @Motti: 1. The @ sign is on a totally unintuitive location on Swiss keyboards, so my German mind often fails entering it, as it did in this case. 2. Tried to answer improve the answer accordingly, please review.

Answer (score 4):

Title is a DOM property not a QTP property, you can use DOM properties for identification by appending `attribute/` to the property name.

[image]